# create graph from attributes of a table

Tags: python, odoo

I want to add a pie chart showing the product with the quantity available, for this I have a table called product and in it is the name with the quantity available. The problem is that I try to create the view but I get an error. The work code is as follows:

```
    <record model = "ir.ui.view" id = "inventory_graph_view">

        <field name = "name"> Inventory </field>

        <field name = "model"> project_rc.product </field>

        <field name = "arch" type = "xml">

            <graph string = "Inventory">

                <field name = "name" type = "row" />

                <field name = "quantity_available" type = "col" />

            </graph>

        </field>

    </record>

    <record model = "ir.actions.act_window" id = "project_rc.product_action_window">

    <field name = "name"> Product registration </field> <! - add name to outside screen ->

    <field name = "res_model"> project_rc.product </field>

    <field name = "view_mode"> tree, form, graph </field>

    </record>
```

**and the error presented is the following:**

Fields in 'groupby' must be regular database-persisted fields (no function or related fields), or function fields with store=True

help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field `quantity_available` is compute field in your model, compute field doesn't store field value in the database but computes it on the fly. The graph feature relies on database `groupby` functionality which can not perform here because column not available in database. What you have to do is set `store=True` in the `quantity_available` field definition. Also in case of stored compute value, you must define `@api.depends` carefully, as recompute of the stored value depends on the decorator.

Comment: I have a problem, which means that when I put the store = true, the quantity available increases me considerably in one product, which causes others to remain at 0. I enclose test images about my problem so that I understand better. 
image without store = true -----> https://ibb.co/ygFBByn  
image with store = true -----> https://ibb.co/QMTTjLF

Comment: I think that came out because the store had put it later, so now I modified the quantity and it was modified correctly, thank you very much and I hope that is the solution hahaha